# Google PubSub .NET SDK PublishAsync Hangs

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-platform, grpc, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to publish a message to a Google PubSub topic. Everything seems to work correctly but the call to `PublishAsync` just hangs. I suspect that it might be an auth problem but I'm also not seeing anything turn up in the logs. The message is a gRPC/protobuf message.

```cs
public async Task LogEvent(DataEvent dataEvent)
{
    try
    {
        if (dataEvent == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataEvent));

        var topicNameString = dataEvent.RecordId.ToTopicName();
        var topicName = TopicName.FromProjectTopic(ProjectId, topicNameString);

        var publisherClient = await PublisherClient.CreateAsync(topicName).ConfigureAwait(false);

        var publisherServiceApiClient = PublisherServiceApiClient.Create();

        var result = await publisherClient.PublishAsync(dataEvent).ConfigureAwait(false);
        logger.LogTrace("Logged data event {dataEvent} {message}", dataEvent, result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //TODO: Handle failures here. This should retry several times
        logger.LogError(ex, "Error on LogEvent {dataEvent}", dataEvent);
    }
}

public static class Ext
{
    public static string ToTopicName(this string name)
    => $"[TOPICPATH]{name}";


    public static async Task<List<string>> GetTopicNames(this PublisherServiceApiClient publisherServiceApiClient, string projectId)
    {
        var topics = await publisherServiceApiClient.GetTopics(projectId).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var topicNames = topics.SelectMany(t => t.Topics.Select(t2 => t2.Name)).ToList();
        return topicNames;
    }

    public static async Task<List<ListTopicsResponse>> GetTopics(this PublisherServiceApiClient publisherServiceApiClient, string projectId)
    {
        if (publisherServiceApiClient == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(publisherServiceApiClient));
        var pagedAsyncEnumerable = publisherServiceApiClient.ListTopicsAsync(new ListTopicsRequest { ProjectAsProjectName = new ProjectName(projectId) });
        var topics = await pagedAsyncEnumerable.AsRawResponses().ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return topics;
    }
}
```

Comment: It turns out that I had to send the short version of the topic name. The bug in the API is that there is no validation exception.